# why am I able to change the values of a Pandas dataframe within a function when the dataframe is not passed in?

Tags: python, pandas, scope

As you can see below, the dataframe df is initialized outside the function, but I was able to change the value of the 'A' column inside func() without passing df as a parameter into the function.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[10,20,30]}, index=list('abc'))

def func():

    df['A']=[0,0,0]

func()
print(df)

   A   B
a  0  10
b  0  20
c  0  30
```

However, in this similar case below, variable v is declared outside func2(), yet I am unable to change its value in the function, why is that?

```
v=5
def func2():
    v=10
print(v)

5
```

Comment: Your `df` is a global variable and is a pointer to a data object.

Comment: Maybe do some reading on variable scope and namespaces in Python.  [Here](https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/) is one guide.

Comment: why is df a global variable when I didn't declare it as global?

Comment: `df` is in the global namespace.  Since there isn't a df in the local namespace of `func`, Python assigns to the global `df`.  However, in your second piece of code you are defining a new local variable named `v`.  This is therefore not the same as the `v` in the global scope.

Comment: @Bill thanks. I think the key is to realize that assigning something new to df['A'] is different than assigning something new to df.

Comment: Other languages are more explicit about when they are declaring a new variable vs. assigning a new value to an existing variable. E.g. `int x = 0.0;` vs. `x = 2.0;`.  Personally I try to avoid using global variables in Python functions and if I do, use the `global` keyword to be explicit.  E.g. `global df` in your code above.